# Including new js file into Magento 2.2?

Tags: jquery, css, magento, less, magento2

I'm including a new js file at:

```
app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/web/js/flexslider.js
```

Which is giving me the following errors:

```
flexslider.js:1218 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at flexslider.js:1218
(anonymous) @ flexslider.js:1218
jquery-migrate.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
(index):427 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function
    at (index):427
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5226)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:4878)
```

My requirejs-config has this in it:

```
var config = {

    // When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
    deps: [
        "/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/en_US/js/flexslider.js"
    ]
};
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: did you run "setup:upgrade" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: system loaded jquery after your js (your js need jquery for working).

try with this.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'flexslider': 'js/flexslider',
        }
    }, 
    paths: {
        'flexslider': 'js/flexslider',
    },
    shim: {
        'flexslider': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```